# Show progress in taskbar Icon using visual basic 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, taskbar

I know there must be some ways to show the progress of something in the task bar icon...

However i found there are some tutorials and librarys to accomplish this, I am not really satisfied with them...

Has anyone experience in doing this, can you reccomand a .dll, post some example code?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you are on .NET 4, you can use the new namespace,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shell(VS.100).aspx

It comes from the WPF Shell Integration project,

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell